# How can I get the type of a class to use as a method parameter?

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class A<T extends Event> {
  void onEvent(T event);
}
```

and a `Class<? extends Event> clazz` object. How can I create an anonymous subclass of `A` with the same generic type parameter as my class object? In other words, how can I get the type from my class object and pass it into a new subclass of `A`?
Something like this:

```
new A<clazz.getType()>() {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(clazz.getType() event) {}
}
```

Comment: You can't, it is impossible to instantiate an abstract class in java. You have to make a class that extends that abstract class, and adds a definition to that method.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific. I edited my post. My main concern is passing the generic type  of the class into the generic type of A.

Comment: `new A()<clazz.getType()>` this is still initializing the abstract class

Comment: Sorry, not initialize. Create an anonymous subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a compiling language so you cannot dynamically change the class type so we have to define if blocks to change the type as per the data.

Your main `Event` class:

```
public class Event {}
```

The `A` class which get the type of class

```
public abstract class A<T extends Event> {
    void onEvent(T t){};
}
```

Sample inherited class

```
public class Sample extends Event {}
```

Simple implementation

```
Sample sample = new Sample();

if (sample instanceof Sample) {

    A<Sample> a = new A<Sample>() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Sample t) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
    };

    // Simple implementation
    a.onEvent(sample);
}
```